# Doctrine custom mapping type schema update

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to create a custom Doctrine mapping type, as per:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types

My class is as follows:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Doctrine\Type;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

/**
 * My custom datatype.
 */
class BinaryStringType extends Type
{

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $platform->getBinaryTypeDeclarationSQL($fieldDeclaration);
    }

    public function getDefaultLength(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $platform->getVarcharDefaultLength();
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'binarystring';
    }
}

?>
```

And in config.yml `doctrine` section:

```
dbal:
    types:
        binarystring: AppBundle\Doctrine\Type\BinaryStringType
```

It (kind of) works, but: running `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update` ALWAYS generates an ALTER TABLE statement, no matter if database is up to date or not.

```
ALTER TABLE xxxx CHANGE column column VARBINARY(24) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by generates an `ALTER TABLE` statement, what is the exact statement that it generates?

Comment: @JasonRoman added the `alter table` statement to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that doctrine is recignising your field as a regular string type rather than your binary string so it is trying to convert it each time.

If you add..

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return true;
}
```

.. to your class then it will add something like `COMMENT \'(DC2Type:binarystring)\'` to the alter table call in your migration (and a comment hint to your DB) so it is recognised as your field type in the future.